# HierarchicalDataTemplate for self referencing table

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I try to implement `HierarchicalDataTemplate` for the [self referencing table](http://www.codecapers.com/post/Using-Self-Referencing-Tables-With-Entity-Framework.aspx) in Silverlight 4.

[image]

**It shows all items in the TreeView like 1 level instead of the hierarchical view. It should be 3 levels of the items.**

[image]

So I got stuck how to do it...  Any clue? Thank you!

```
<UserControl x:Class="TreeViewCRUD.MainPage"
 xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"             
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:Crud="clr-namespace:TreeViewCRUD"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid>
           <sdk:TreeView Height="403" Margin="0,0,0,0"  Name="TreeView1" Background="Beige" >
        <sdk:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Divisions}" >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="5,0"></TextBlock>
           </sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>                
        </sdk:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </sdk:TreeView>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**and C#**

```
 void client_GetDivisionsCompleted(object sender, MyService.GetDivisionsCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            var lst = e.Result;
            try
            {
                TreeView1.DataContext = lst;
                // TreeView1.ItemsSource = lst;
                TreeView1.ItemsSource =  lst.Where(a=>a.DivisionID != null);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
                MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Where specifically are you stuck?  What is the expected behavior and how does the current behavior differ from that?

Comment: @cadrell0 It shows for me all items in the TreeView like 1 level instead of the Hierarchical view. It should be 3 levels of the items.

Comment: @cadrell0 I just updated my question please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that your XAML is correct(mostly) and the data is the issue.  I assume `lst` contains some data like

```
ID    DivisionID  Divisions1
1     null        (List<Division>)
2     1           (List<Division>)
3     2           (List<Division>)
```

When what you really need `lst` to be is

```
ID    DivisionID  Divisions1
1     null        (List<Division>)
```

Now lst[0].Divisions1 would be

```
ID    DivisionID  Divisions1
2     1           (List<Division>)
```

And finally lst[0].Divisions1[0].Divisions1 would be

```
ID    DivisionID  Divisions1
3     2           (List<Division>)
```

Verify that the data from WCF is coming with the Navigation Properties intact.  Even if `lst` shows all 3 elements instead just the top level one, you should be able to filter that down client side.

The last thing I noticed is that you are using `ItemsSource="{Binding Divisions}"` for your binding.  However, in the class diagram, the properties name is `Divisions1`

Comment: Thanks for the input! In fact under WCF I have this:   return db.Divisions.ToList(); So nothing special there. Could u suggest if I have to convert Divisions table into some intermediate LIST or ...? If yes then how it could be done? Do u mean under WCF  I have to build the structure that u suggesting?

Comment: Well I found the solution at the RIA Services level http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9929050/recursive-select-via-linq The last thing is sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate