# Recursive select via LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, recursive-query

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [linq to sql recursive query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072166/linq-to-sql-recursive-query)

I got stuck with having to build a Recursive select via LINQ for the self referencing table.

[image]

I use this class:

```
public class DivisionHierarchy
{
    public Division Division { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<DivisionHierarchy> Divisions { get; set; }
}
```

and I created this function but somehow it is infinite.

```
public IEnumerable<DivisionHierarchy> GetDivisionHierarchy(IEnumerable<Division> allDivisions, Division parentDivision)
{
    Guid? parentDivisionId = null;

    if (parentDivision != null)
         parentDivisionId = parentDivision.DivisionID;

    var childDivisions = allDivisions.Where(e => e.DivisionID == parentDivisionId);

    Collection<DivisionHierarchy> hierarchy = new Collection<DivisionHierarchy>();

    foreach (var div in childDivisions)
       hierarchy.Add(new DivisionHierarchy() { Division = div, Divisions = GetDivisionHierarchy(allDivisions, div) });

     return hierarchy;
}
```

Any clue where I can start?

Thank you!

P.S. Are there any others ways to do it?

---

UPDATES based on http://www.scip.be/index.php?Page=ArticlesNET18#AsHierarchy

I found my errors.

There are 2 things to implement:
1. The root node should be created under the database.

[image]

2. I changed code a little bit.

   ```
   Guid divisionID = Guid.Parse("5b487b3d-e9be-413f-b611-2fd7491e0d0d"); // Hardcoded somehow
   var rootDivision = db.Divisions.Where(i => i.ID == divisionID).FirstOrDefault();
   var divisionHierarchy = GetDivisionHierarchy(db.Divisions.AsEnumerable(), rootDivision);
   ```

   ...

   ```
    public IEnumerable<DivisionHierarchy> GetDivisionHierarchy(IEnumerable<Division> allDivisions, Division parentDivision)
           {
               Guid? parentDivisionId = null;

               if (parentDivision != null)
                   parentDivisionId = parentDivision.ID;

               var childDivisions = allDivisions.Where(division => division.DivisionID == parentDivisionId);

               Collection<DivisionHierarchy> hierarchy = new Collection<DivisionHierarchy>();

               foreach (var div in childDivisions)
               {
                   DivisionHierarchy divisionHierarchy = new DivisionHierarchy();
                   divisionHierarchy.Division = div;
                   divisionHierarchy.Divisions = GetDivisionHierarchy(allDivisions, div);
                   hierarchy.Add(divisionHierarchy);
               }

               return hierarchy;
           }
   ```

Comment: Have you tried to search for the answer at least at stack overflow? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072166/linq-to-sql-recursive-query 

Looks like a straight duplicate.

Comment: @Ruslan It doesn't has the answer I need. I need to get the entire tree into some var.

Comment: @Peretz If you need the whole thing then you're best off just pulling down the list as is and mapping it to a tree in memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would load the divisions in an non-recursive way and then set up the recursive relations in code. Here is an example, which does this in a lazy way

```
public class Division
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int DivisionID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    private static List<Division> _divisions;
    public static List<Division> Divisions
    {
        get
        {
            if (_divisions == null) {
                LoadAndSetUpDivisionsHierarchy();
            }
            return _divisions;
        }
    }

    private static Dictionary<int, Division> _divisionsByID;
    public static Dictionary<int, Division> DivisionsByID
    {
        get
        {
            if (_divisionsByID == null) {
                LoadAndSetUpDivisionsHierarchy();
            }
            return _divisionsByID;
        }
    }

    private static Division _root;
    public static Division Root
    {
        get
        {
            if (_root == null) {
                LoadAndSetUpDivisionsHierarchy();
            }
            return _root;
        }
    }

    private Division _parentDivision;
    public Division ParentDivision
    {
        get
        {
            if (_parentDivision == null && DivisionID != 0) {
                _parentDivision = DivisionsByID[DivisionID];

            }
            return _parentDivision;
        }
    }

    private List<Division> _subDivisions = new List<Division>();
    public List<Division> SubDivisions
    {
        get { return _subDivisions; }
    }

    private static void LoadAndSetUpDivisionsHierarchyHierarchy()
    {
        // Load the divisions in a non-recursive way using LINQ
        // (details not shown here).
        _divisions = LoadDivisions();

        // Add the divisions in a dictionary by id
        _divisionsByID = new Dictionary<int, Division>(_divisions.Count);
        foreach (Division division in _divisions) {
            _divisionsByID.Add(division.ID, division);
        }

        // Define sub-divisions and root division
        foreach (Division division in _divisions) {
            if (division.DivisionID == 0) {
                _root = division;
            } else if (division.ParentDivision != null) {
                division.ParentDivision.SubDivisions.Add(division);
            }
        }
    }

    private static List<Division> LoadDivisions()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input!!! Let me investigate it...

Comment: Laziness is good for infinite recursion.

Comment: I added a static `Root` property and code define its value. `Root` is the entry point into the hierarchy.

Comment: I completed the hierarchy by adding sub-divisions. Now the divisions build a hierarchy by themselves and do not require a separate data structure for a hierarchy. The hierachy is access through the static `Root` property. In addition, you can access a list (`Divisions`) and a dictionary of divisions (`DivisionsByID`) given as static properties.