# LinqToSQL recursive select

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

Before you marked it as duplicated, I did extensive search and it doesn't provide my answer. I've looked through
[Recursive select via LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9929050/recursive-select-via-linq) and [linq to sql recursive query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072166/linq-to-sql-recursive-query) and http://www.scip.be/index.php?Page=ArticlesNET18#AsHierarchy

What I need is the reverse of the on the 2nd and 3rd link. But I can't figure out how to do it.

Look at this example:

```
EmployeeId  Name  ManagerId
----------------------------
    1        A     null
    2        B     1
    3        C     1
    4        D     3
    5        E     2
    6        F     5
```

What I need is that if **A** is login, **A** will need to see all of his/her subordinate **recursively**. In this case **A** will see details of everyone.

So:

1. If **B** login, then he/she should see: **E**, **F** and his/her self (**B**)
2. If **C** login, then he/she should see: **D** and his/her self (**C**)
3. If **D** login, then he/she should see: his/her self (**D**)
4. If **E** login, then he/she should see: **F** and his/her self (**E**)
5. If **F** login, then he/she should see: his/her self (**F**)

My question is, how to create linqtosql that is recursive?

My current solution is to read all employee records to the list then do recursive check. If I have a lot of employee, it seems like a waste of resources to load all records to list.

Any idea?

Cheers

Comment: Depending on the number of employees, if you write a query to return only the required amount of data (e.g just the three columns shown) - you may find it more efficient to read all of the data into memory & run a recursive method on that data. Otherwise what you will find is that an SQL query is required per managed employee at each level of recursion - the overheads of multiple small queries may exceed that of a single large query. For example, if you have one senior manager (managerID != null) overseeing 10 managers each overseeing 5 staff - that would require 61 queries.

Comment: Hi Paul, it is for a medium size organization. It is around few hundreds of employees. There will be a lot of operation (approving expenses, bonus, kpi, etc...). I just tried to make it as efficient as possible (if possible). Right now, I am loading all the list and filter it via my recursive functions. Just curious if there is a way to do it. If not, I'll live with loading all records to the list.

Comment: If it is just a few hundred employees, then a single query to get all data sounds like it wouldn't be improved that much & could possibly be made worse. The best way of improving things would be to use stored procedures & let the database server do the work - so you have one query & only the required data returned.

Comment: Does it have to be recursive? If you know the maximum number of levels, you could do something like  `Employees.Where(r=> r.EmployeeId == id || r.Manager.EmployeeId == id || r.Manager.Manager.EmployeeId == id || r.Manager.Manager.Manager.EmployeeId == id ... )`

Comment: Can you give some idea of what data structure you want the answer to be in?

Comment: @PaulF, oh ok... so you think it will be OK? In that case I'll just stick with what I have. Plus the last link that I sent also read all records from database before filter it.

Comment: @sgmoore, I do not know how many level there will be. And it  doesn't have to be recursive.

Comment: @NetMage, I am hoping a linqtosql syntax. but I'll take anything :)

Comment: Perhaps I should have said what data structure you want the result to be in.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution would probably to do this in Sql.

If you can't amend the Sql database, you could use ExecuteQuery to execute a Sql cte directly, eg something like

```
int employeeId = 1;

var query = this.ExecuteQuery<Employee>(
@" 
; WITH cte 
As
(   
    SELECT Employee.* FROM  Employee   WHERE EmployeeId = {0}

    UNION All SELECT so.* FROM Employee so INNER JOIN cte ON cte.EmployeeID = so.ManagerId
)

SELECT * FROM cte
", new object[] { employeeId } );
```

Obviously you will need to test this.

Note, if you do something like `query.Select(a=> new { a.EmployeeID, a.Name})` then this will still perform a select * in the background and the other columns will be downloaded to the client and then ignored, but you can create a class which has the fields you want and change the cte to return just those columns.